# CKEditor doesn't load on Django admin site

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I deployed my project on Heroku but when I login to the admin site on Django, CKEditor doesn't load. I'm using CKEditor in order to implement RichTextField in my models.

**This is the error**

```
GET https://portfolio-jpl.herokuapp.com/static/ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
        
GET https://portfolio-jpl.herokuapp.com/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**Settings.py file**

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
    'general',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'

# Other settings
STATIC_URL_DEFAULT_IMAGE = '/static/base/img/default.png'
STATIC_URL_PROFILE_IMAGE = '/static/base/img/personal/'
STATIC_URL_IMG = '/static/base/img/portfolio/'
```

I'm a little confused due to I don't have CKEditor folder in the static directory.

Comment: display `STATIC_ROOT` and check if you have `ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js` in this folder (full path can be `<project-folder>/staticfiles/ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js`

Comment: @furas Inside `staticfiles` folder I have 2 folders: `admin` and `base`. Inside them I have the same folders such as `css`, `img`, `js`, and `vendor`. I don't have any ckeditor folder or file in my project

Comment: your error shows that it want to read `GET https://portfolio-jpl.herokuapp.com/static/ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js` so it want to read `/static/ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js` and it means it want it read `ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js` from `staticfiles` - so you use wrong urls in template. It may need `/static/admin/js/ckeditor-init.js` if you have `ckeditor-init.js` in this folder. Eventually you could read it from external servers `CDN` - ie `https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/34.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js` like in documentation https://cdn.ckeditor.com/

Comment: @furas I manually added those files in the required directory and I pushed the changes and the errors disappeared in the console, but it still not showing the RichTextField in my Django admin site. Is there something else that I have to show?

Comment: you can check DevTools in Chrome/Firefox - maybe there is JavaScript error. OR maybe it needs some changes in template - maybe it needs to add some class to normal `TextField`.